# comparing two text fields one is disabled another one is manually enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table inside a form, the rows and data inside the rows are generated from the back end automatically. Well all the columns are disabled, so that the user can not edit it but one column is editable. on submit compare the value from editable column and value in quanity column and display a alert message if value of editable is more.

```js
function validateAvaliable(){
  var aproducts = document.getElementById("available-quanity").value;
  var sproducts = document.getElementById("send-quanity").value;
  console.log(aproducts);
  console.log(sproducts );
  if (aproducts < sproducts) {
    alert("send products are more");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
            <form onsubmit="validateAvaliable()" class="available-products-table" id="available-products-table"  name="available-products">
        <table class="table">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Avaliable Products</legend>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>S.no</th>
                      <th>Product Name</th>
                      <th>Product ID</th>
                      <th>Quanity</th>
                      <th>Brand</th>
                      <th>Color</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                      <th>Quanity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-sno" id="available-sno" disabled value="1"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-name" id="available-name" disabled value="shoes"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-id" id="available-id" disabled value="123"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="available-quanity" id="available-quanity" disabled value="50"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-brand" id="available-brand" disabled value="adidas"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="available-color" id="available-color" disabled value="black"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="product-status" id="product-status"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="send-quanity" id="send-quanity" required></td>
                  </tr>
                  
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Enter Franchise ID</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="send-franchise-is" id="product-status" required></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></td>
                    
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
            </fieldset>
        </table>
        </form>
        </div>
```

When I try to debug it it's getting the values but if statement is skipping.
I need the code in javascript or Jquery.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `parseInt()` and it did the trick:

```js
function validateAvaliable() {
  var aproducts = parseInt(document.getElementById("available-quanity").value);
  var sproducts = parseInt(document.getElementById("send-quanity").value);
  console.log(aproducts);
  console.log(sproducts);
  if (aproducts < sproducts) {
    alert("send products are more");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <form onsubmit="return validateAvaliable()" class="available-products-table" id="available-products-table" name="available-products">
    <table class="table">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Avaliable Products</legend>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>S.no</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Product ID</th>
            <th>Quanity</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Quanity</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="available-sno" id="available-sno" disabled value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="available-name" id="available-name" disabled value="shoes"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="available-id" id="available-id" disabled value="123"></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="available-quanity" id="available-quanity" disabled value="50"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="available-brand" id="available-brand" disabled value="adidas"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="available-color" id="available-color" disabled value="black"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="product-status" id="product-status"></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="send-quanity" id="send-quanity" required></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Enter Franchise ID</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="send-franchise-is" id="product-status" required></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"></td>

          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </fieldset>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the compression is working but after the closing the alert message. the form is submitting, how to stop it.

Comment: Updated. You need to add `return` in your `onsubmit`

Comment: Thanks Again its Working

Comment: You’re welcome, If it helped you, please [upvote and accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Happy Coding! :)

Comment: Hard coding an onsubmit in the HTML and return false are not really "the jQuery way".  You might look into .on() and .preventDefault() ...